# To what degree is CHAYKA radio navigation publically available?

Tags: radio-navigation

With most of the [Loran-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loran-C) network in Europe shut off in Europe since 2015, public positioning services seems limited to satellite navigation (GPS/GLONASS/Galileo).

However, to what degree is the equivalent [CHAYKA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHAYKA) hyperbolic navigation network still usable? I'm having trouble finding information more recent than a decade old, making it possible that the system is no longer available.

Comment: You might find more information if your search for its Russian name, `Чайка`, with your favorite search engine. Looks like it actually means "seagull" so you might get more hits than desired.

Comment: I have attempted that, but have not been able to find a conclusive answer with my limited Russian.

Comment: I'll try but my Russian is also very limited.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be much information after 2010, but I'll keep on looking, it's kinda interesting and I can exercise my pidgin Russian.

Comment: `The masts at Dudinka and Taymylyr (demolished in 2009) were 460 metres high. ` this gives a clue that it may have been dismantled a while back.

Comment: @Raffles Yes, the Wikipedia page is up to date to that point, as the GRI 5960 chain is clearly no more.

Comment: I just stumbled upon  [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110816150649/http://www.internavigation.ru/page.phtml?p=95) if you're willing to go through your favorite translator :D Even then they mention 2004 - 2007.

Comment: They seem to talk about GLONASS, so maybe the CHAKYA system is defunct.